# Instagram - media user and caption user stored separately

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I'm playing around with instagram's API and got a JSON object as below, assume it's stored in variable `media`

```
{
    id:'1222XXXXXX_XXXXX',
    created_time: "1459991213",
    user: {
        username: "user1",
        profile_picture: "http://link",
        id: "7xxxx",
        full_name: "SomeName"
    },
    caption: {
        created_time: "1459991213",
        text: "hello",
        from: {
            username: "user1",
            profile_picture: "http://link",
            id: "7xxxx",
            full_name: "SomeName"
        },            
        id: "1222831055034209838"
    }
    images:{...}
}
```

Notice that

- `media.user` and `media.caption.from` are same user info.
- `media.created_time` and `media.caption.created_time` are the same.

I'm curious why Instagram duplicate these information and if it's possible for them to have different values.

I tried to upload an image without a caption and added caption later but the `media.caption.created_time` simply inherits the value from `media.created_time`.

I don't know how to let other people to add/edit caption of my own image, so now sure if `media.caption.from` can be different from `media.user`.

Could anyone advise on this?